# How to complete Chapter 4 in Mafia 2?

Tags: mafia-2

The mission objective at the start of the chapter, when I get up at Joe's apartment, is to "meet Joe at Freddy's with a gun and lockpicks".

I have the guns, my ammo is full, I have the lockpicks. However, the cutscene just doesn't load ANYWHERE inside Freddy's. I Googled it, it seems to be normal, and start immediately when we enter Freddys. I can also see Joe and the other man sitting in Freddy's. I walk up to them. Nothing happens.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Hope you haven't been waiting all this time to continue playing Mafia II, but in case you're still stuck at the Chapter 4 scene, try downloading a save-game and loading the chapter from that.

This download should contain a savegame: http://www.mediafire.com/?ob9w23mgonw3289

A solution is to download a 100% completed Mafia II save-game, so when you replace your save-game files (back them up) with the downloaded ones, you can continue the game with them. You can find Mafia II save-game files by searching on the internet, this is just a link to the ones I downloaded.

Comment: Hi Ylj, could you summarize the contents of the video/link so that this answer is still valid if the video goes away?